# Simple form filling automation with downloading feature in different formats

Tags: pdf, document-management, forms

I'm just looking for software either open source or proprietary for simple filling forms automation. I have consider any price options.

For example i have a document with some predefined structure (on server in any form ) with few fields which must filled by a person. After submiting results i would like to download this file in `doc` or `pdf` format.
Example:
'Order number: %num
Date: %date and time %t'

Comment: "*i have a document*" What document type? Online? Something you build and host on your own server? What OS? Price? Please read http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information and [edit] your question

Comment: Google Spreadsheet has something similar, won't bet on this, though.

Comment: Watch [this video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6YwDME0Fl1c) for some ideas. Read [this free ebook](http://pages.itextpdf.com/ebook-stackoverflow-questions.html) for some code.

Comment: You need to provide more details about your environment.  What is showing your forms to the user - a web server?  What programming language? JODReports or Docmosis might be ideal.